# PostgreSQL: How do I split range based on the critical value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample data in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database like follows:

```
id    c_value   start_r   end_r    m_value
1     171       61        201      19.3
2     89        59        119      22.1
3     47        137       227      18.9
3     47        227       287      0.0
3     47        287       347      27.1
3     47        347       47       6.5
4     65        120       150      14.1
```

Column explanation: `Id (integer)` and not unique. `C_value (integer)` is the critical value. `start_r (integer)` and `end_r (integer)` are the start and end values of the range while `m_value (numeric)` is the mean value.

For each row, I only need to modify `start_r` and `end_r` based on `c_value`. That is, I need to split range into slices if it encounters the critical value otherwise output will be same. The expected outcome is as follows:

```
id    c_value   start_r   end_r    m_value
1     171       61        171      19.3
1     171       171       201      19.3
2     89        59        89       22.1
2     89        89        119      22.1
3     47        137       227      18.9
3     47        227       287      0.0
3     47        287       347      27.1
3     47        347       47       6.5
4     65        120       150      14.1
```

Can someone suggest me how do I split range based on critical value?

Comment: Hint: LEAST(), GREATEST(), UNION ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a simple `union all`:

```
select id, c_value, start_r, end_r, m_value
from t
where c_value <= start_r or c_value >= end_r
union all
select id, c_value, start_r, c_value, m_value
from t
where c_value > start_r and c_value < end_r
union all
select id, c_value, c_value, end_r, m_value
from t
where c_value > start_r and c_value < end_r;
```